# Trouble with getting input from Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner

I'm just learning a bit of Java and figuring out how things work.
I've managed to get the first window to "pop up",
but I can't get the answer to "pop up", and help would be great.

```
package classwork;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class computeArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your radius?");
        double radius = input.nextDouble();

        double area = radius * radius * 3.14159;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," the area for the circle of radius is " + radius + " is " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get the value from the input dialog?

Comment: I believe that Scanner is used for command line input (I may be wrong on this).

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with the fact that you are crossing purposes, GUI's allow users to enter data one way, consoles do it another, you should avoid using both, instead, simply use the GUI functionality which is available to you...

So, the core issue is `double radius =input.nextDouble();` is waiting for input...although you've just prompted the user for input...

Another issue you might have, is doubles can be formatted using scientific notation, which I'm sure is awesome and all, but isn't always particularly useful to some users, so you might consider using `NumberFormat` to format the double values into what the rest of us can understand ;)

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your radius?");
// User cancelled or closed the dialog
if (value != null) {
    try {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(value);
        double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the circle of radius " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(radius) + " is " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(area));
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value + " is not a valid double, try again");
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for some more details